# Block diagonalisation of $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, block-matrices

I'm attempting to find a 4x4 matrix, P, that will convert my matrices,

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

and,

$B = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

into block diagonal matrices. I can see that A is already a block diagonal matrix (with a 2x2 block and then two 1x1 blocks).

Does this mean I only need to find a matrix P that converts B into block diagonal form and I am done or do I have to solve the problem simultaneously for both matrices?

I have found that I can fully diagonalise A by,

$S = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1&1\\0&0&2&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

and I have also proved that B is not diagonalisable.

Any help in how to block diagonalise B alone or even better how to block diagonalise A and B simultaneously would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd want to look at the the [Jordan Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_form)

Comment: Thanks I've looked this up and managed to block diagonalise my matrix B using a matrix J. I'm now attempting to find out if there is a combination of the matrix S and the matrix J that will block diagonlise both matrices A and B. Thanks